# devices call not returning all devices; account permission granted

Tags: nest-device-access

I have 4 Nest devices: 1 camera, 2 doorbells, and 1 thermostat.  All 4 have all permissions granted to my Device Access project via [PCM](https://nestservices.google.com/partnerconnections).  However, when I [make a device list call](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize#make_a_device_list_call), only the 2 doorbells and camera are returned in the JSON.  The thermostat is not returned.

It was returning calls up until January 11, 2020, and then just stopped reporting.  I had made no changes (that I know of) to device access.  At that point, it stopped being returned by the device call as well.

I have tried disabling and re-enabling access from my project to the thermostat, and still have no luck.  What else can I do to troubleshoot or resolve?

[Image: PCM showing Thermostat access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAFRg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

- Delete the device from your account via the Nest app
- Reset the account info in the device (not a full factory reset)
- Re-add the device via the app
- Authorize access to the 'new' device in PCM
- Re-query devices